# Vue Array Class Proxy Not Reacting

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a class that extends `Array`, and as part of it, I want to intercept changes that are made to its properties, so I use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), which is what I return from its constructor.  It works just fine until I try to use it in my Vue component.  See [this example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

When the page first loads, you'll see the console log for `Collection 1` in the `watchEffect`, which is the expected result.  Then when you click the `Add Filter` button, you'll see that the display doesn't update and the `watchEffect` doesn't fire... expectation is that we'd get the console log like when the page loaded.  However, if you inspect `collection1`, you'll see that the value was added.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and how I can fix it?  It feels like maybe my proxy is being tripped up with Vue's proxy wrapper, but I don't know enough about the internals to say that confidently.

**Collection.js**

```
export class MyCollection extends Array {
  constructor(data) {
    super();
    this.add(data);
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(target, prop, value) {
        target[prop] = value;
        if (prop === 'filters') {
          const add = []
          target.records.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.id === target.filters) {
              add.push(item)
            }
          })
          target.add(add);
        }
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
  
  addFilters() {
    this.filters = 1
  }
  
  add(items) {
    this.length = 0;
    items = Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items];
    this.records = items;
    console.log('here', this.records, this);
    items.forEach((item) => this.push(item))
  }
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
  import {watchEffect, computed, ref, toRaw} from "vue";
  import {MyCollection} from "./Collection.js";
  
  const collection1 = $ref(new MyCollection([{id: 1, display: 'one'}, {id: 2, display: 'two'}]));
  
  watchEffect(() => {
    console.log("wow", collection1);
  });
  
  const onClickUpdate1 =() =>  {
    collection1.addFilters();
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Collection 1
    <button @click='onClickUpdate1'>
      Add Filter
    </button>
  </div>
  <div v-for="item in collection1" :key="item.id">
    {{item.display}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this edit I made to your code](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

I have changed a few things:

1. changed to `script setup` for better readability
2. changed `computed` to `reactive` using the `$red` syntax from [reactivity transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactivity-transform)
3. You were adding items with `name: 'three'` and displaying **`item.display`**. I changed that bit to add with `display: 'three'`.

It works now and I suspect the difference is in having changed from computed to reactive though I'm not sure. I'm going to read about it a bit more and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the post and fiddle to resolve the issue in your 3rd bullet point (thanks for pointing that out).  Yeah, reactive works, but I need to monitor the prop that changes in my original fiddle, so I'll have to use `computed`.

Comment: I figured out from the documentation. By default, `computed` properties are read-only. You will have to set explicit getters and setters. [See here: writable computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed).

Comment: Yeah, that'd be if I was doing an assignment to collection1 like `collection1.value = [{id: 3, display: "test"}]`, but I'm pushing onto an existing array.

Comment: @incutonez I'm not seeing the problem here with using `reactive` (or `ref`). Why can't you watch the change with `reactive`/`ref` in your fiddle? It works just fine in the answer's fiddle.

Comment: @incutonez `import { ref } from 'vue'`, change your `computed` to `const collection1 = ref(new Collection(props.options));`, and presto.

Comment: @tony19 Because that will only work for the initial value of `props.options`, but when it changes outside of my component, it won't react and update `collection1`

Comment: @tony19, okay, this is my fault... I didn't have the full use case up.  Check the edit in my post... instead of pushing onto the array, we now add a filter, which filters the underlying records and changes the array's items using `add`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but I may have also found a bug in Vue, which [I've reported](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5841).  What I had to change was calling the `receiver`'s method instead of the `target`'s method in the set trap of `MyCollection`.  [Fiddle](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

**MyCollection.js**

```
export class MyCollection extends Array {
  constructor(data) {
    super();
    this.add(data);
    return new Proxy(this, {
      set(target, prop, value, receiver) {
        target[prop] = value;
        if (prop === 'filters') {
          const add = []
          target.records.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.id === target.filters) {
              add.push(item)
            }
          })
          // IMPORTANT: Had to use receiver here instead of target
          receiver.add(add);
        }
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
  
  addFilters() {
    this.filters = 1
  }
  
  add(items) {
    this.length = 0;
    items = Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items];
    this.records = items;
    items.forEach((item) => this.push(item))
  }
}
```

The second issue, which I think is the bug, is that I still can't use a `computed` method for this.  However, I can use a `ref` and `watchEffect` to achieve the same thing.

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
  import {watchEffect, computed, ref, toRaw} from "vue";
  const props = defineProps({
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: [{id: 1, display: 'one'}, {id: 2, display: 'two'}]
    }
  })
  import {MyCollection} from "./Collection.js";
  
  const collection1 = ref(null);
  const collection2 = computed(() => new MyCollection(props.options))
  
  // Workaround for not being able to use computed
  watchEffect(() => {
    collection1.value = new MyCollection(props.options)
  })
  watchEffect(() => {
    console.log("collection1", collection1.value.length);
  });
  // THIS WILL NOT FIRE WHEN ADD FILTER IS CLICKED
  watchEffect(() => {
    console.log("collection2", collection2.value.length);
  });
  
  const onClickUpdate1 =() =>  {
    collection1.value.addFilters();
    collection2.value.addFilters();
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click='onClickUpdate1'>
      Add Filter
    </button>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div style="margin-right: 1rem;">
      Collection 1
      <div v-for="item in collection1" :key="item.id">
        {{item.display}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      Collection 2
      <div v-for="item in collection2" :key="item.id">
        {{item.display}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```